# Как собрать характеристики товара и отправить их на e-mail?

Tags: jquery, post, html, css, php

Здравствуйте!

Есть лендинг с товаром на простом html+css:

[image]

По принципу интернет-магазина с него нужно собрать характеристики (цвет, размер, количество) и отправить на e-mail по клику на кнопку оформить заказ, куда в свою очередь вписать имя и телефон. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @alex_uni, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно собирать в переменные запросом типа `var value = $('#_VALUE_CONTAINER_ID_).html();`, где *VALUE_CONTAINER_ID* — id span'а или div'а, содержащего значение характеристики. Собрав значения, отправляй их php-скрипту посредством `$.post()` (google-поиск не помешает).

А вообще старайся четко ставить задачу: фрагмент исходника хотя бы в студию...

Comment: "А вообще старайся четко ставить задачу: фрагмент исходника хотя бы в студию..."
http://jsfiddle.net/qme344a6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Как бы это странно не звучало, можно обойтись и без PHP :)

- Регистрируемся тут: http://mandrill.com/ , получаем API_KEY он бесплатный для тарифа до 12к писем в месяц
- Серриализуем форму: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
- Готовите им JSON: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html
- Отсылаете и получаете статус (отравлено, не отправлено)

Comment: А как мне сериализовать элементы списка LMS[размеры] и цвет(картинка) - ведь они не классические input, textarea и select?